# Unable to create superuser in django due to not working in TTY

Tags: python, django, eclipse, tty

I go through first django tutorial from djangoproject.com and at the very beginning of part 2, which is creating superuser when I run `"python manage.py createsuperuser"` I get the following message back:

```
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually.
```

I get the same message when I go on to create superuser after running `syncdb`.

I am working on Eclipse for Windows 7, and Django 1.7.1 together with Python 2.7.8.

Comment: How is python manage.py createsuperuser being run?  Is it being run from Eclipse somehow or via the windows command line?

Comment: From eclipse custom command tool for Django projects.

Comment: Could we try running 'python manage.py createsuperuser' from the windows command line instead of the eclipse custom command tool?

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot for not trying this myself. Worked like a charm, thanks Kevin.

Answer (score 21):

When using the Git Bash and to correct the above error message try to append `winpty`  
 i.e. for example:

```
$ winpty python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use '...'):
```

Comment: What does `wintpy` do?

Comment: @LoukasPap `winpty` is a Windows software package providing an interface similar to a Unix pty-master for communicating with Windows console programs

Answer (score 5):

You can create a superuser using django shell (`python manage.py shell`)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser(username='YourUsername', password='hunter2', email='your@email.com')
```

Comment: It's helpful, but it fights against consequences not reasons.

Answer (score 4):

if you are in virtualenv, `cd` into your virtualenv and activate it. then try these steps:

```
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: I installed django from windows command line without using virtualenv or any other installation managing programs. Is there a way around my problem without installing more stuff?
Besides, would it help if I got them now?

Comment: @PJM did you run these 3 commands? you dont need to install aynthing to get this to work

Comment: Yes I did, still the same message.

Comment: Use the commandline tool instead of the custom command in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I am a Windows10 user. I tried to run `py manage.py createsuperuser` command using `Git Bash` console, but error has been thrown. Then I switched `Git Bash` to native `Windows Command Line` with **administrator privileges**, and re-run command - it was working.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Windows PowerShell" or "Windows Cmd" and then use same command. Git command interface has some restriction.

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

in cmd prompt, then apply migration by

```
cd mysite
mysite:

python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

after that

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser) you can do it without TTY

```
    DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=psw \
    python manage.py createsuperuser --email=admin@admin.com --noinput
```

also, you can set DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD as the environment variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are Windows user using GitBash terminal and trying to create super for admin it won't work instead of that use command prompt in administrative privilege it works

Gitbash terminal error

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run "manage.py createsuperuser" in your project to create one manually.
```

Error Resolved Using Command Prompt

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'user'): admin
Email address:
Password:
Password (again):
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.
```

This might be helpful for others. Do Upvote for this if it works for you

Answer (score -1):

Use this command :

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate

python3 manage.py createsuperuser

python manage.py runserver
```

Your error is probably:

```
[Error `You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, content types, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)`][1]
```

check you yo directory with Tree command:[`tree`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43mGL.png)

Then run Make migration :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQMr.png)

then create superuser with the `python3 manage.py createsuperuser`command :